# CustomList in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, custom-lists

when i run my app just get this error:

> Error:(123, 45) java: incompatible types:
>   com.special.ResideMenuDemo.NoBoringFeragment cannot be converted to
>   android.app.Activity

and the error line is:

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, name, family, metrics);
```

i just dont get it, u know i just change my class from activity to fragment and extend from fragment, if this can help u.
and and when i want get actionBarSize in this line of my app my IDE show this error to me:

> Error:(223, 9) java: cannot find symbol
>         symbol:   method getTheme()
>         location: class com.special.ResideMenuDemo.NoBoringFeragment
>   can u help me to figure this out?

edit:
i just add ,u source, maybe it clear things out:

my java code:

```
package com.special.ResideMenuDemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.*;

import com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.NoBoringActionBarActivity;
import com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.AlphaForegroundColorSpan;
import com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.KenBurnsView;
import com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.ParallaxImageView;

/**
 * Created by milad_000 on 31/01/2015.
 */
public class NoBoringFeragment extends Fragment {
    ////////////////////////////////-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private DisplayMetrics metrics;
    String[] name = {
            " کرمی فرماندار شهرستان سرخه با اشاره به تهاجم فرهنگی دشمنان اسلام و تلاش برای جداسازی جوانان از آرمانهای انقلاب افزود: بایدسازو کاری دیده شود تا اجلاسیه شهدای امسال به سمت جوان محوری هدایت شود ،چراکه بهترین کار برای پاسداشت ارزشهای انقلاب و دفاع مقدس در زمان",
            " حمیدرضا",
            " عباسعلی"
    };
    String[] family = {
            " ",
            " اسفنجاني",
            " الله دادی"
    };


    private static final String TAG = "NoBoringActionBarActivity";
    private int mActionBarTitleColor;
    private int mActionBarHeight;
    private int mHeaderHeight;
    private int mMinHeaderTranslation;
    private ListView mListView;
    private KenBurnsView mHeaderPicture;
    private ImageView mHeaderLogo;
    private View mHeader;
    private View mPlaceHolderView;
    private AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator mSmoothInterpolator;

    private RectF mRect1 = new RectF();
    private RectF mRect2 = new RectF();

    private AlphaForegroundColorSpan mAlphaForegroundColorSpan;
    private SpannableString mSpannableString;

    private TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    ////////////////////////////////*********************************************************************************

    private View parentView;

    ////////////////////////////////*********************************************************************************

    ////////////////////////////////-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        parentView= inflater.inflate(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.layout.activity_noboringactionbar, container, false);
        mSmoothInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
        mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.dimen.header_height);
        mMinHeaderTranslation = -mHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight();

      //  setContentView(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.layout.activity_noboringactionbar);

        mListView = (ListView) parentView.findViewById(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.id.listview);
        mHeader = parentView.findViewById(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.id.header);
        mHeaderPicture = (KenBurnsView) getView().findViewById(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.id.header_picture);
        mHeaderPicture.setResourceIds(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.drawable.picture0, com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.drawable.picture1);
        mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) parentView.findViewById(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.id.header_logo);

        mActionBarTitleColor = getResources().getColor(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.color.actionbar_title_color);

        mSpannableString = new SpannableString(getString(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.string.noboringactionbar_title));
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(mActionBarTitleColor);

        setupActionBar();
   //     setupListView();

        return parentView;



    }

    private void setupListView() {

        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, name, family, metrics);
        mListView.setDivider(null);
        mListView.setDividerHeight(0);
        mPlaceHolderView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView, false);
        mListView.addHeaderView(mPlaceHolderView);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);





        mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                int scrollY = getScrollY();
                //sticky actionbar
                mHeader.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation));
                //header_logo --> actionbar icon
                float ratio = clamp(mHeader.getTranslationY() / mMinHeaderTranslation, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                interpolate(mHeaderLogo, getActionBarIconView(), mSmoothInterpolator.getInterpolation(ratio));
                //actionbar title alpha
                //getActionBarTitleView().setAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
                //---------------------------------
                //better way thanks to @cyrilmottier
                setTitleAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTitleAlpha(float alpha) {
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan.setAlpha(alpha);
        mSpannableString.setSpan(mAlphaForegroundColorSpan, 0, mSpannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mSpannableString);
    }

    public static float clamp(float value, float min, float max) {
        return Math.max(min,Math.min(value, max));
    }

    private void interpolate(View view1, View view2, float interpolation) {
        getOnScreenRect(mRect1, view1);
        getOnScreenRect(mRect2, view2);

        float scaleX = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.width() / mRect1.width() - 1.0F);
        float scaleY = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.height() / mRect1.height() - 1.0F);
        float translationX = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.left + mRect2.right - mRect1.left - mRect1.right));
        float translationY = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.top + mRect2.bottom - mRect1.top - mRect1.bottom));

        view1.setTranslationX(translationX);
        view1.setTranslationY(translationY - mHeader.getTranslationY());
        view1.setScaleX(scaleX);
        view1.setScaleY(scaleY);
    }

    private RectF getOnScreenRect(RectF rect, View view) {
        rect.set(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
        return rect;
    }

    public int getScrollY() {
        View c = mListView.getChildAt(0);
        if (c == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int firstVisiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int top = c.getTop();

        int headerHeight = 0;
        if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
            headerHeight = mPlaceHolderView.getHeight();
        }

        return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.drawable.ic_transparent);

        //getActionBarTitleView().setAlpha(0f);
    }

    private ImageView getActionBarIconView() {
        return (ImageView) parentView.findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    }

    /*private TextView getActionBarTitleView() {
        int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        return (TextView) findViewById(id);
    }*/

    public int getActionBarHeight() {
        if (mActionBarHeight != 0) {
            return mActionBarHeight;
        }
        getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(mTypedValue.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        return mActionBarHeight;
    }

    public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private DisplayMetrics metrics_;
        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] name;
        private final String[] family;

        public CustomList(Activity context,String[] name,String[] family , DisplayMetrics metrics ) {
            super(context, com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.layout.viewlisting, name);
            this.context = context;
            this.name = name;
            this.family = family;
            this.metrics_ = metrics;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView= inflater.inflate(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.layout.viewlisting, null, true);
            TextView nameTxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.id.name);
            TextView familyTxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.id.family);

            nameTxt.setText(name[position]);
            familyTxt.setText(family[position]);

            Animation animation = null;
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.anim.push_left_in);
            rowView.startAnimation(animation);

            return rowView;
        }

    }

}
```

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NoBoringActionBarActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height">

        <com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.KenBurnsView
            android:id="@+id/header_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/picture0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_logo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/header_logo_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_logo_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_header_logo" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you cannot just change an activity into a fragment, more changes are needed. for starters, fragments still need a surrounding activity to run in.

Comment: @peedee i know it, i change a lots of my code, but just don's know whats is the reason of this 2 errors.

Comment: Please post your fragment's source code.

Comment: @Milad Na I meant edit your question and post the source.

Comment: @MiladNa I have added an answer. Please let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: @iRuth ok can u answer my comment in bottom of ur answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since your adapter's constructor is this

```
public CustomList(Activity context,String[] name,String[] family , DisplayMetrics metrics)
```

you should replace

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, name, family, metrics);
```

with this

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), name, family, metrics);
```

The reason is because `this` in `CustomList adapter = new CustomList(this, name, family, metrics);` refers to the `Fragment`, but what is correct is the `Activity`.

For the second error, you should try replacing

`getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);`

with

`getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);`.

**Update**

Your custom adapter extends the ArrayAdapter class and so I suggest you change

```
public CustomList(Activity context,String[] name,String[] family , DisplayMetrics metrics)
```

to

```
public CustomList(Context context,String[] name,String[] family , DisplayMetrics metrics)
```

Comment: ok first of all thank u for ur answer.
my first problem still staring at me , in my message box
but gooood news is getThem() problem is solved.
do u have any idea about first one?@iRuth

Comment: ok i change that, and now it just give me error in :
 this.context = context;
and thr error is :
'Error:(239, 28) java: incompatible types: android.content.Context cannot be converted to android.app.Activity'

Comment: Change `private final Activity context;` to `private final Context context;`.

Comment: ok tanks it works but after fix that another error just slap me in the face:error come from this line : LayoutInflater inflater =context.getLayoutInflater().; so i look up in the sof and find this:   `code`LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);`code asdasdasda`  it help me but when i compile and click to select this fragment, my app show a force stop dialog. i have no idea.

Comment: Change `LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();` to `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`.

Comment: oh god another error , i changed code, as u say and get this error: `Error:(251, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable inflater
  location: class com.special.ResideMenuDemo.NoBoringFeragment.CustomList`
in this line :
           `View rowView=inflater.inflate(com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar.R.layout.viewlisting, null, true);`

Comment: Oh my bad. It should have been `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`. But you should have known that :). That's a simple error to fix.

Comment: i get sick of this class , the force error still is there when i choose to run this fragment, and i get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/flavienlaurent/notboringactionbar/NoBoringActionBarActivity;`
can i send my whole project to u and u just check ?
i am just sooo frustrate of this project.

Comment: Do you have a class called NoBoringActionBarActivity?

Comment: Sory for my delay, yes i have a class whit that name: `public class NoBoringFeragment extends Fragment` it extended from activity and i just changed it to fragment and do changes it neeed.

Comment: The error is there because you made a reference to `NoBoringActionBarActivity` and the compiler cannot find the class.